# Search for database objects created on a specific day?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to query my db for objects of an arbitrary model created on a certain day, what's a good way to do this?

In an sql query I used the following to query the objects created yesterday.

where (created_at AT TIME ZONE 'EDT') > (now() AT TIME ZONE 'EDT')::DATE - 1
  and (created_at AT TIME ZONE 'EDT') < (now() AT TIME ZONE 'EDT')::DATE

I want to do the same thing in ruby with ActiveRecord calls.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would do the cast on the database and select the current date there, instead of doing it with a range. You can do this with DATE(created_at) (Will result in "2013-11-01") Then inject the param in the where:

```
Model.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today)
```

If it's used on more places then one it would be good to create a scope as Morner suggested:

```
scope :created_today { where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today) }
```

with name:

```
scope :created_today_with_name lambda do |name| 
  where("DATE(created_at) = ? AND name = ?", Date.today, name)
end
```

or chain it:

```
scope :created_today_with_name lambda do |name| 
  where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today).where(name: name)
end
```

Then call it as:

```
Model.created_today_with_name('Joe')
```

Comment: You're right it's a bit light. Let me edit it to clarify the answer.

Comment: I know this is another question but how can I combine this command with another, so that I could get all the objects created today and have a name containing "foo"

Comment: No problem see my adjusted answer.

Comment: I'm voting this down because in the absence of an index on the DATE() expression (which some RDBMSs support) this is likely to cause a full table scan. I'd go with the more complex range expression (encapsulated in a scope to hide the slightly higher degree of complexity, as in Momer's answer), as the query optimiser can use a regular index on created_at, and has a better chance of accurately estimating the cardinality of the result set.

Answer (score 3):

An example, as a scope, for all items that were created today:

```
scope :created_today, -> { where('created_at between ? AND ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day) }
```

More information at the [PostgreSQL site](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-comparison.html)